# How can I modify the face colors of a mesh object with vispy when they're already set?

Tags: python, colors, mesh, cube, vispy

I've got a problem trying to modify the colors of the faces of my Mesh cube with vispy. I an using the set_face_colors() method but it's not working. I think I just don't know how to use it properly...

Here's my code. The goal really is just dispalying 2 cubes with the same color when pressing 'a'.

```
from vispy import app, scene, geometry
import numpy as np

class MonCanvas(scene.SceneCanvas):
    def on_key_press(self,event):
        global cube1, cube2, c1data, c2data
        print("You pressed '{}'".format(event.text))
        if '{}'.format(event.text) == 'a':
            print(c2data.get_face_colors())
            print(c1data)
            cube1 = cube1.mesh_data.set_face_colors([[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,0.5,0,1],[1,0.5,0,1]])
            print(c1data)

fenetre = MonCanvas(title="Fenêtre principale", size=(2000,1000), keys="interactive")

view = fenetre.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = 'turntable'
view.camera.distance = 10

c1data = geometry.MeshData(vertices = np.array([[0.5,0.5,-0.5],[0.5,-0.5,-0.5],[-0.5,0.5,-0.5],[-0.5,-0.5,-0.5],[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,-0.5,0.5],[-0.5,0.5,0.5],[-0.5,-0.5,0.5]]), edges = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,7],[5,1],[5,4],[5,7],[6,2],[6,4],[6,7]]), faces = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[5,6,7],[4,5,6],[0,1,5],[0,5,4],[2,3,7],[2,7,6],[1,3,7],[1,7,5],[0,2,6],[0,6,4]]))
c1data.set_face_colors([[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]])
cube1 = scene.visuals.Mesh(meshdata = c1data)
view.add(cube1)

c2data = geometry.MeshData(vertices = np.array([[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,-0.5,0.5],[-0.5,0.5,0.5],[-0.5,-0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5,1.5],[0.5,-0.5,1.5],[-0.5,0.5,1.5],[-0.5,-0.5,1.5]]), edges = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,7],[5,1],[5,4],[5,7],[6,2],[6,4],[6,7]]), faces = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[5,6,7],[4,5,6],[0,1,5],[0,5,4],[2,3,7],[2,7,6],[1,3,7],[1,7,5],[0,2,6],[0,6,4]]))
c2data.set_face_colors([[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,0.5,0,1],[1,0.5,0,1]])
cube2 = scene.visuals.Mesh(meshdata = c2data)
view.add(cube2)

fenetre.show()
app.run()
```

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? Side note: `'{}'.format(event.text)` can just be `event.text` I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I don't get an error, it is just not doing what I want it to do which is changing cube1 colors.

Comment: I get the cubes in a window but nothing happens when I press "a". I also tried : c1data.set_face_colors() with the colors I want but c1data is not modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two things that need changing in your code. First, you reassign `cube1` in your key press handler when you set the face colors. `set_face_colors` doesn't return anything so you're setting `cube1` to `None`. Not necessarily a problem since vispy will hold on to references, but definitely not something you intended to do I'm guessing.

Next, you've updated the `MeshData` object underneath the `MeshVisual`, but haven't told the `MeshVisual`. As an optimization, `MeshVisual` will only update the GPU-side data when it is told that it has changed. This is done automatically when you use methods like `mesh.set_data`. In cases like yours when you're updating the lower-level `MeshData` object (a perfectly fine thing to do I think), you can tell the mesh to update by doing `cube1.mesh_data_changed()` right after the `set_face_colors` call.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it's working. Thank you so much !